# Regex get words between a two words and these words should be available only once

Tags: regex

For all the examples need 'a programming' as output

Example 1 : This is a programming test.

REGEX : a+\sprogramming -- Working

Example 2 : This is a test programming. This is a programming test

REGEX : a+\s(?!test)\sprogramming -- Working

Example 3 : This is a test programming. This is a basic a programming test

REGEX : a+\s(?!test)(.+)\sprogramming -- Not working

Actual O/P : a basic a programming

Expected O/P : a programming

That is, need 'a' printed only once.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've read this question three times and I still don't understand...

Comment: If you only want one 'a', remove the `+` quantifier.

Comment: why not simply /.*(a programming).*/ ?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
REGEX : .*(a programming).*
```

O/p expected:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > "This is a test programming. This is a basic a programming test ".match(/.*(a programming).*/)
 => #<MatchData "This is a test programming. This is a basic a programming test " 1:"a programming"> 
1.9.3p194 :002 > "This is a programming test. ".match(/.*(a programming).*/) => #<MatchData "This is a programming test. " 1:"a programming"> 
1.9.3p194 :003 > "This is a test programming. This is a programming test ".match(/.*(a programming).*/)
 => #<MatchData "This is a test programming. This is a programming test " 1:"a programming">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question.

If you're looking to match a word between two words, such as "a" and "test", then you do this:

```
a\s+(\S+)\s+test
```

(The `\S` with a capital "S" matches *non*-whitespace characters.)

If you want only the *last* such instance, then:

```
a\s+(\S+)\s+test(?!.*a\s+(\S+)\s+test)
```

(Notice what's inside the negative lookahead assertion is a copy of the part outside.)

In addition, you would want to use word boundaries, *e.g.*

```
\ba\s+(\S+)\s+test\b(?!.*\ba\s+(\S+)\s+test\b)
```